# Special language constants make the .RC file uneditable

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resource-files

I am using VS2008.

I use Soluling to translate a Test.RC file containing some string tables, and it generates constants of some special languages, such as LANG_HINDI, which is defined in Windows kits, such as

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared\ntdef.h
```

So I create a header file LangConsts.h to include these constants.

Then in the Test.RC file, I add the following line:

```
#include "LangConsts.h"
```

Thus the Test.rc can be opened in VS2008 successfully, the special languages will be recognized as below:

[image]

And the file can be complied and linked in the project successfully.

However, whenever I modify the resources, such as change the version number, and save the resource file, then VS2008 will try to resave all the string tables.

Then when I try to rebuild the project, I will get many errors:

```
>.\ResDLL.rc(9786) : error RC2144 : PRIMARY LANGUAGE ID not a number
1>.\ResDLL.rc(9794) : error RC2135 : file not found: STRINGTABLE
1>.\ResDLL.rc(9796) : error RC2135 : file not found: M
1>.\ResDLL.rc(9798) : error RC2135 : file not found: 64
```

Then I open ResDLL.rc and check what's wrong with it, and find VS2008 just remove the following line:

```
#include "LangConsts.h"
```

And line 9786 contains a language constant:

```
LANGUAGE LANG_AZERI_LATIN, SUBLANG_AZERI_LATIN
```

which is only defined in LangConsts.h.

So how to prevent VS2008 from damaging the .RC file?